# converting a list of strings into a tuple

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

Hello i am trying to do a dictionary by using Python,
What needs to be done is python reads a text file which has values inside such as:

```
good    buono
```

What I have done was, open the file with file function and replace tabs and add reversed comma to create a list so it looks like

```
["('good', 'buono')", "('afternoon', 'pomeriggo')",... and so on
```

but the problem is type of each word translation is not a tuple, it is string when I am trying to see 1st element(number 0) it shows me the value as

```
"('good', 'buono')"
```

which is a string. I need to use dict formula so that i can convert the type into dictionary but I cannot because it is list of strings(has to be list of tuples)

So how can I convert that list of strings into list of tuples?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that every pair of words is on a separate line in your file, you could do this:

```
mydict = {line.split()[0]: line.split()[1] for line in myfile}
```

This transforms a file like

```
good    buono
afternoon   pomeriggo
thanks    grazie
```

into

```
{"good": "buono", "afternoon": "pomeriggo", "thanks": "grazie"}
```

No need for tuples along the way.

[`.split()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) splits the input string on whitespace, removing any leading/trailing whitespace:

```
>>> "  good\tbuono  \n".split()
['good', 'buono']
```

Comment: Danke Herr Pietzcker! Can you also explain what does the split function does in the loop?
Thanks

Comment: Information about `split()` can be found [here](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split).   Essentially, it takes a string, and based on a specific delimiter (" " by default), it separates that string into individual pieces, placing them in a list.

Comment: [`mydict = dict(imap(str.split, myfile))`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8623506/4279)

Comment: @TimPietzcker This will call `split()` twice for each line, right? Just curious, is there a way to do the same thing but one split per line?

Comment: @jb.: Yes, see J.F. Sebastian's comment.

Answer (score 4):

```
with open('input.txt') as f:
     result = map(str.split, f)
     # -> [['good', 'buono'], ['afternoon', 'pomeriggo']]
     d = dict(result)
     # -> {'good': 'buono', 'afternoon': 'pomeriggo'}
```

Comment: This doesn't return the string as a list of tuples, though.

Comment: @Makoto that's a good thing. The string is an unnecessary middle step.

Comment: @Makoto: `map(tuple, result)` if list of lists is not sufficient and you need list of tuples.

Comment: Hold the phone; I've just tried this code.  It seems to split the individual elements of the string itself, and not split it based on the whitespace.

Comment: @Makoto: read [str.split](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) and try [again](http://ideone.com/KLkwE).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian:  I see, reading the entire file in all at once instead of line by line.  Not bad.  Alright then, I'm convinced.

Comment: @Makoto: `f` is a file. It must be crystal clear from `with open('input.txt') as f` statement. Use `f = StringIO(your_string)` or `f = your_string.splitlines()` to accept input as a single string.

Answer (score 1):

`ast` will work as @onemach suggested, but you may want to read the strings in as tuples instead.

Snippet:

```
li = []
with open("file.txt", 'r') as f:
    li.append(tuple(f.readline().split('\t')))
```

This will split the string about the tab, and place it into a tuple object, which is then appended into a list.